# Python Wand vs imagemagick brightness-contrast command

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I try to use Wand and can't find any mappings for brightness-contrast command.

[source img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzti2.jpg)

- Tried to use modulate for changing brightness:

  `value = 100 + value # no changes = 0 in console and 100 in wand
  img.modulate(brightness=value)`

and I got some strange artefacts with white pixels:
[brightness change attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jj6Q.jpg)

- For working with contrast Wand has just contrast_stretch() and I can't understand how to do something like this

  `convert '-brightness-contrast 0x%d'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, `-brightness-contrast` just calls `-function Polynomial` methods which is implemented in [wand](/questions/tagged/wand). Some very simple math is needed to translate the `brightness x contrast` arguments into `slop x intercept`.

```py
import math
from wand.image import Image

class MyImage(Image):
    def brightness_contrast(self, brightness=0.0, contrast=0.0):
        slope=math.tan((math.pi * (contrast/100.0+1.0)/4.0))
        if slope < 0.0:
          slope=0.0
        intercept=brightness/100.0+((100-brightness)/200.0)*(1.0-slope)
        self.function("polynomial", [slope, intercept])

with MyImage(filename="rose:") as img:
    img.brightness_contrast(0.0, 10.0)
    img.save(filename="rose.png")
```

[image: rose.png]

Comment: very simple :)  Yes, it's works, but I don't understand how. However imagemagick is blackbox for me too. I just can't understand why Wand developers didn't create similar API like in shell.

Comment: As an explanation, if you want to increase brightness by 10% then use the equivalent of ImageMagick -modulate(110,100,100). But you seem to want to change the contrast and not the brightest. You could do that using the equivalent of -level 0x90% or +level 0x110%. Using the equivalent of -function polynomial in linear mode, you have two arguments a and b, which are the equivalent of slope and intercept. Slope controls contrast and intercept controls brightness.

Comment: Absolutely! [`Image.modulate`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.modulate) & [`Image.level`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html#wand.image.Image.level) exists on the `wand` library.

Comment: Guys, thank you very match for answers. I have another question about Wand/Imagemagick can you look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327442/matching-wandimagemagick-on-camanjs-functionality